# Is a finite group which is generated by two characteristic abelian subgroup always abelian?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a finite group. If there exist two characteristic subgroups $H,K$ of $G$ such that $H$ and $K$ are abelian and generate the whole group $G$. Then can we conclude that $G$ is abelian?

All I know is that $G$ must be nilpotent, so it suffices to consider $p$-groups.

Comment: we can say that $G''=1$ for such groups.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few examples of order $32$. For example the semidirect product $\langle a,b,c,d \rangle \rtimes \langle t \rangle$ of an elementary abelian group $\langle a,b,c,d \rangle$ of order $16$ with a cyclic group $\langle t \rangle$ of order $2$, with $a^t=b$, $b^t=a$, $c^t=d$, $d^t=c$ is generated by the characteristic abelian subgroups $\langle a,b,c,d \rangle$ and $\langle ab,cd,t \rangle$.

(I found this using a computer search.)

Comment: That's not an automorphism. $t$ has order $2$ and $at$ has order $4$.