# Is a finite group which is generated by two fully invariant abelian subgroups always abelian?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a finite group satisfying there exist two fully invariant subgroups $H,K$ of $G$ such that $H$ and $K$ are abelian and generate the whole group $G$. Then can we conclude that $G$ is abelian? All I know is that $G$ is a nilpotent group of class $2$.

This question is inspired by an [older question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1272566/is-a-finite-group-which-is-generated-by-two-characteristic-abelian-subgroup-alwa). And by an fully invariant subgroup I mean a subgroup $H$ of $G$ such that $f(H)\leqslant H$ for **all endomorphism** $f$ of $G$.

Comment: There is a term "Fully characteristic subgroup" http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fully_characteristic_subgroup .

Comment: @AlexW I've fixed it. Thanks a lot.